# how to install GridSpec Matplotlib module

Tags: matplotlib

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS, Python 2.6.5, Matplotlib 0.99.1.2-3ubuntu1,

I try to import GridSpec module http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/gridspec.html but I can not find a way to import it, install it or download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISTM the simplest solution is simply to upgrade your version of matplotlib.  gridspec was added to mainline back in [May 2010](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commits/master/lib/matplotlib/gridspec.py), but 0.99.1 dates to 
[fall 2009](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.99.1/).  It was never really a separate module-- looks like it was folded into the base less than a week after it was announced with a mpl_toolkits location.

Comment: thanks you DSM,
I can install it using
sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib